# Авторизация с помощью модуля requests на сайте bitcoinru.org

Tags: python, парсер, https, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте, но не получается и меня кидает обратно логиниться. Помогите разобраться в чём моя ошибка. Делаю первые шаги в веб-скрапинге и парсинге. Цель авторизоваться и считать количество BTC.

```
import lxml.html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login = 'mylogin'
password = 'mypass'
url = 'https://bitcoinru.org/'

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 YaBrowser/20.3.1.197 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language':'ru,en;q=0.9',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '271',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxEHBUogoIAis8UHA',
'Host': 'bitcoinru.org',
'Origin': 'https://bitcoinru.org',
'Referer': 'https://bitcoinru.org/',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin'
}
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers)
page = lxml.html.fromstring(data.content)

form = page.forms[0]
form.fields['openEmail'] = login
form.fields['openPass'] = password

print(page.forms[0].fields['openEmail'])

response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
#response = session.post(url, data=form.form_values())
print('onLoginDone' in response.text)

soap = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print(soap.find("li", attrs={"id": "walletBalance"}))
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Выберите другой сайт для обучения. На этом авторизация сильно замороченная. Или попробуйте selenium. А вообще для сохранения авторизации используйте конструкцию `with requests.Session() as session:`

Answer (score 0):

Делаем запрос сюда:

```
import requests


data = {
    'uid': '1',
    'key': '12345678901234567890123456789012',
    'setmodule': 'addresses',
    'request': 'bal',
    'address': 'Номер вашего кошелька',

}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://coinb.in/api/', params=data)
    print(r.text)
```

Получаем такой ответ:

```
<request>
<result>1</result>
<balance>0</balance>
<response>balance+returned</response>
</request>
```

Где `<balance>0</balance>` и есть наш баланс

Источник: F12 -> сеть

Т.е. сам сайт нужен только для создания кошелька, а данные он получает путём запроса на другой домен с номером кошелька в параметрах.

И вообще он выглядит довольно подозрительно, я бы не стал пользоваться. Но, решать вам

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Скажите пожалуйста, почему сайт показался вам подозрительным? Просто планирую прикрутить через него оплату к Telegram боту.

Comment: Сделан топорно, дизайна толком нет, отзывов тоже толком нет. Лучше использовать другой популярнй кошелек типа метамаска или блокчейн